# Do water tokens on canteens count against a player's 12 token limit?

Tags: parks

[The rules](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1898/8501/files/Rules-NEWLOGO-Small.pdf?v=12672166157712510236) state:

> Players can carry up to 12 tokens with them. If you have more than 12
> at the end of your turn, you must discard down to 12.

Tokens on canteens are not part of a player's supply:

> To fill a Canteen, place a [water token] gained that turn onto the
> Canteen instead of into your supply and perform the Canteen's action.

But the token limit rule does not use the word "supply", it just says "carry". Are water tokens on a canteen considered to be "carried", and thus subject to the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no official answer on an FAQ or the Rulebook, I'd say they're not counted.

The reasons are essentially what you already listed. The rules explicitly say they're not part of your supply, as well as that you can't use those tokens for anything else.

> [...] To fill a Canteen, place a gained that turn onto the Canteen *instead of into your supply* and perform the Canteen’s action. You can have any number of Canteens, *and any number of your Canteens can be filled on a turn* if you gain multiple. Once a Canteen is filled, the remains on it until the end of the Season and *cannot be used any other way.*

If the canteen water was subject to the 12 limit, saying "Any number of your canteens can be filled" would not be true; the limit would be up to 12. This is a stretch, but I feel like this rule would've been worded differently if it was subject to the limit, something like "and any number of your canteens can be filled on a turn, up to the maximum carrying limit, if you gain multiple."